# In which file should I define my ModelForm that I'm creating for a Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have created a Model in my /models.py for which the code is shown below. I'm trying to define a ModelForm for my Question Model class. In which file should I define my ModelForm class for it?

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    """ Defines logical structure of question object. """
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

Comment: Create a separate file named `forms.py` and then here you can declare your ModelForm by importing models from app.models

Comment: literally, you can define the form's definition anywhere in your projects. But, it's advisable to define those things in **`forms.py`** file inside the *django app* directory, which makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

By creating a file forms.py inside your app, add following codes

```
from django import forms

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Question
    fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this pattern.

1. DJango creates various files when you create the project and app. (e.g. Models.py, Admin.py etc) but some files it doesn't create which are app specific like urls.py and forms.py.
2. To get these files you have to manually create them in the **app** you want them in, by simply right clicking on the **app directory** and creating a new file named either **forms.py** or **urls.py**.
3. Remeber Django and python are case sensitive so make sure to type in correct names and name-spacing.